# Laravel5.2 custom directive variable type change

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a problem with creating custom Laravel blade directive. I want to create directive `@message($message)`. Argument expected is an associative array (and I am 100% sure `$message` contains an array). This is my code:

**index.blade.php:**

```
<?php $message = array("item" => "value"); ?>

@if(isset($message))
    @message($message)
@endif
```

**Custom directive declaration:**

```
    Blade::directive('message', function($message){
         if(is_array($message)){
             return "<?php print 'is array'; ?>";
         }else{
             return "<?php print 'is not array'; ?>";
         }
    });
```

No matter what i do, output always says, it is not an array. I searched everywhere, but I didnt find an answer. Can someone explain?

Comment: can you try dd($message) before calling is_array($message)?

Comment: I already did it. The following is displayed: "($message)"

Comment: then you can see it is not an array. you should be sure that you are passing the correct variable to the view.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I am 100% sure for $message variable, that it is array. I updated code above.

Comment: if it is an array then dd() will output it as an array

Comment: Well, that is the issue i need to explain. As you can see, $message is declared right above @message() call. It is clearly array. After passing $message variable as an argument, it changes, and I do not know why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106614/discussion-between-mohamed-bouallegue-and-fusion).